# Flyway Migration Issue: Handling Baseline Script Validation Post Schema Alteration

Tags: migration, flyway, baseline

I have a baseline script (B001_baseline.sql) which was the first in a series of migration scripts.
After this baseline script was generated and applied, a column (OldColumn) in an external database (not part of the project directly) was removed.
I updated a view in my project that referenced this now-nonexistent column.

Now, when trying to generate a new migration script (to reflect the updated view), Flyway throws an error during validation, seemingly attempting to re-validate the baseline script against the current database state.

For context i use Flyway Desktop and the error occurs when i try to generate new migration scripts

#### Migration B001_baseline.sql failed

---

SQL State  : S0001

Error Code : 207

Message    : Invalid column name (OldColumn)

#### Attempts to Resolve:

- I have considered disabling schema validation for the baseline (`validateOnMigrate = false`), but I'm concerned about the implications for other scripts.
- I am hesitant to modify the baseline script as it has been executed in other environments.
- Creating a new baseline at this stage seems tricky due to existing deployment in multiple environments.

#### Questions:

1. Is there a recommended approach in Flyway to handle such a scenario where the baseline script validation fails due to schema changes made afterward?
2. Are there any Redgate Flyway Desktop-specific features or settings that can help bypass this validation error or handle the schema changes more effectively?
3. What are the best practices for managing and updating baseline scripts in Flyway, especially when dealing with external database dependencies?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: my two cents: set `baselineOnMigrate` to true.